# Save (and retrieve) module configurations in Prestashop

Tags: php, module, prestashop

Good day all.
I have a simple module on prestashop, I'd like to add a configuration flag, a boolean value the user can enable/disable to configure the module. really easy.
I've done it the "vikings" way, by using a form in tpl and then read with php the POST variables.

But now I'd like to do it in a proper way.

What I've so far is my form, created in the module:

```
protected function getConfigForm()
    {

        return array(
            'form' => array(
                'legend' => array(
                'title' => $this->l('Settings'),
                'icon' => 'icon-cogs',
                ),
                'input' => array(
                    array(
                        'type' => 'switch',
                        'label' => $this->l('a label'),
                        'name' => 'MULTISHOP_LANGUAGE_MODE',
                        'is_bool' => true,
                        'desc' => $this->l('use any language on every shop'),
                        'values' => array(
                            array(
                                'id' => 'active_on',
                                'value' => true,
                                'label' => $this->l('Enabled')
                            ),
                            array(
                                'id' => 'active_off',
                                'value' => false,
                                'label' => $this->l('Disabled')
                            )
                        )
                    )

                ),
                'submit' => array(
                    'title' => $this->l('Save'),
                ),
            ),
        );
}
```

then I got the functions to set and get the values:

```
protected function getConfigFormValues()
    {

       return array(
            'MULTISHOP_LANGUAGE_MODE' => Configuration::get('MULTISHOP_LANGUAGE_MODE', true)
        );

    }

    /**
     * Save form data.
     */
    protected function postProcess()
    {
    Configuration::updateValue('MULTISHOP_LANGUAGE_MODE', Tools::getValue('MULTISHOP_LANGUAGE_MODE'));


    }
```

I'm forgetting something? because the switch on the form, never change, everytime I reload the form, the switch is on "false".

the db never change after submitting (saving) the form.

thanks in advance.

UPDATE:
the db actually change, when submitting the form, the value of that field become `NULL`

Answer (score 0):

I've managed to solve this issue, I don't know why, but writing this function in this way makes everything works as a charm.

```
protected function getConfigFormValues()
    {

       return array(
            'HREFLANGFORPRESTASHOP_MULTISHOP_LANGUAGE_MODE' => Configuration::get('HREFLANGFORPRESTASHOP_MULTISHOP_LANGUAGE_MODE')

        );

    }
```

note, I've deleted the second parameter of the  return array, which was `true`